# Is it possible to set a pointer to an instance of a class to nullptr when the destructor is called?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, linked-list, nullptr

I am attempting to create a linked list for a class project.  My node class has a pointer which points to the linked node and another pointer which points to a specialized book class.

```
class Node{
private:
    Book *data;
    Node *linkedLink;
public:
    Node(Book *inputedData);
    Book* getBook();
    Node* getLinked();
    void changeLinked(Node *newLink);
    Node& operator=( const Node& rhs );

    ~Node(); //deconstructor
};
```

My professor has provided a driver that we **cannot** change.  In this driver, he has the following code:

```
// (bookList is an instance of my LinkedList class)
// (and getFirst() returns my LinkedList's head node)

while (bookList.getFirst() != nullptr)
{
    Node * t = partsList.pop_front();
    delete t;
}
```

The following is my node classes destructor:

```
Node::~Node(){
    delete data; //this deletes the book class that data points to.
    delete linkedLink;
}
```

The problem is, I need the variable (t) that points to the instance of a Node class to be set to `nullptr` after it's done releasing `*data` and `*linkedLink`.  But I **can't** change my professors driver, which means that I would have to do this in my Node classes destructor.  I'm stumped on how I would do this... Wouldn't I have to set the Node class to nullptr to break out of the while loop from my professors driver?  Or maybe I'm completely off track and overthinking this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

=======[ Edit ]=======

My Node class can only point to one other Node class, no more.  It must be a "singly linked" list, not "double linked".

=======[ Edit 2.0 ]========

for those asking for more code, the following is my LinkedList class.

```
class List{
private:
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    int count;
public:
    List();
    List(Node firstLink);

    ~List(); //deconstructor

    Node* getFirst() const;
    Node* getLast() const;

    void push_back(Node *data);
    void push_front(Node *data);

    Node* pop_front();
    Node* pop_back();

    int getLength() const;
    List& operator=(const List& that);
};
```

Comment: if you make change your linked list from being "singly linked" to "doubly linked" you can do this easily. In a doubly linked list you will have a pointer to the nodes before and after the current node, this would allow you to signal the previous node to mark its pointer to the current node as null

Comment: "variable that points to my Node class" -- this statement makes no sense. Variables don't point to classes.

Comment: @AlexZywicki That would work great, however my teacher wants us to make a "singly linked" list instead of a double linked class, unfortunately.

Comment: revise your question to make note of that

Comment: @SamVarshavchik sorry for the confusion, I'm talking about "t".  It's pointing to the Node class returned from pop_front().  I need it set to nullptr after the Node class is deleted.

Comment: What does `bookList. getFirst()` return?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik i would assume he meant a variable(pointer) that points to an instance of his node class

Comment: Minor nitpick, but this is what's confusing some people: `t` does not point to the `Node` class. It points to an *instance* of the `Node` class. It points to an object of type `Node` but it doesn't point to the `Node` class itself. This makes more sense in other languages where you can actually have pointers/references to a class (particularly languages with [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming))).

Comment: My bad, sorry, t is pointing to an instance of the Node class, yes.  I made an edit to clarify that.

Comment: we may need to see the remainder or at least more of the code hat you have, i assume the code provided here is just a sample of a larger set of code?

Comment: @Cornstalks bookList.getFirst() returns the head Node from my LinkedList class.

Comment: @AlexZywicki yes it is, I'll make an edit in just a minute

Comment: getFirst() should not return the head it should return the first actual "data node" where you maintain a "head" node that will never hold data but instead will serve as your access point to the list. when removing from the front you will point your head node at the object that follows the node you are removing

Comment: Why the while loop checks `bookList` but is poping Nodes from `partsList`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no facility in the C++ language to automatically set some pointer somewhere to null, when an object gets destroyed. If some pointer needs to be set to null, somewhere, it is the destructor's responsibility to make it happen. Presumably, in some fashion you need to implement some kind of facility that keeps track of pointers to the class instance, and then in the destructor those pointers will be set to null.

Having said that, I'm confident that you are misinterpreting your assignment. I see no need whatsoever for any pointer to be set to null, when the class instance gets destroyed.

In your professor's immutable driver, the call to the `pop_front()` method is going to remove the node from its linked list completely, and return the pointer to the removed node. Your implementation of `pop_front()` is going to completely remove the node from the list, updating all list pointers accordingly, to point to the remaining elements in the list.

At this point, no other pointers to the class instance should exist, except for the pointer being returned from `pop_front()`, and this pointer then immediately gets `delete`d. There won't be any pointers to your class instance that need to be set to null.

Your professor's code is the classical implementation of `std::list`, which manages the exact same task without requiring the destructors of any class instance in `std::list` to worry about setting any pointer to null.